# How do I remove an association in ColdFusion ORM?

Tags: hibernate, orm, coldfusion, null, coldfusion-9

Let's say I have two entities, a `House`:

```
component
{
    property name="Owner" cfc="Owner" fieldtype="many-to-one";
}
```

And an `Owner`:

```
component
{
    property name="Name";
}
```

A `House` may have an `Owner`, but doesn't need to. I have a `House` associated with an `Owner`, but now I want to remove the association. I've tried the following code:

```
 var house = entityLoadByPK("House", 13);
 house.setOwner('');
 entitySave(house);
```

But I get an exception saying that `''` cannot be converted to an id, which makes sense. However, although ColdFusion has a concept of null/undefined, it looks like you can't actually create a null value, only check for them. How would I remove the association in this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have your relationship defined correctly then I believe what you are looking for is:

```
house.setOwner(javaCast('null', ''));
```

Comment: That only applies for one-to-many and many-to-many relationships. In this case, it's a many-to-one (each house can only have one owner), so there is no autogenerated `removeOwner()` function.

Comment: Did you have any luck with my suggestion?

Comment: Yes that worked. Thanks! A bit roundabout though, strikes me as odd that Adobe didn't think about removing an association for many-to-one relationships.